# Read File word by word

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

My problem is to read a text file word by word and recovers every word in a variable. I tried to do:

```
while read ligne; 
do {
for ( i=1; i<= length ($ligne); i++); do
 { var=$(awk '{print $i}' test.txt)}

}done < test.txt
```

But it doesn't work and I have this error:

```
Couldn't parse this for loop
```

Comment: You're missing a `done` on your second `do`.  You only have one `done`, aligning to your `while ... do` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you define words.

If words are separated by one or more spaces, you can do:

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '[\n*]' < file |
  while IFS= read -r word; do
    : echo "$word" here
  done
```

If words are sequences of characters contains `A-Z`, `a-z` and `_`:

```
tr -cs 'A-Za-z_' '[\n*]' < file | ...
```

On historical System V systems, you need to use square brackets `[A-Za-z_]`.

Comment: In addition to blank characters, the first `tr` word splits on brackets. And the second `tr` allows brackets in words, which is disallowed by the explanatory text. I tried to remove the erroneous `[` and `]` in each `tr`, but because of brevity, the site rejected the edit.

Comment: @BarefootIO: It's `[:blank:]`. The second one `[A-Za-z_]` is intended, as required by POSIX.

Comment: Unlike their globbing and regular expression counterparts, `tr` range expressions are not bracketed.

Comment: @BarefootIO: Bracket is required in SysV system, but not in BSD and standardlize by POSIX, I added a note.

Answer (score 4):

Just

```
while read -ra line; 
do
    for word in "${line[@]}";
    do
        echo "$word";
    done;
done < test.txt
```

will split up the file word by word. Change the `echo` to whatever you want to do with the words.

semicolons are added so this can be put into a one-liner.

Comment: @Stéphane, this script just worked without the -ra and the double quotes are in my opinion not necessary since the words does not contain spaces or other delimiters

Comment: One can consider using ${word} when the variable is used to specify the boundaries of the variable name...

Comment: The fact that it worked on simple test input does not mean it can work in the wild where you don't know what the input will be. What if the line contained a `\ ` character?

Comment: According to what @terdon mentioned it is indeed safer to use double quotes around $word, say "${word}"

Comment: If you're using `${line[@]}`, that suggests you want to loop over array elements. However, if you don't use `-a`, that's not what happens. Instead, the line (with backslash processing without -r and with leading and trailing blanks removed) is stored in `$line` aka `${line[0]}`. And when you do `for w in ${line[@]}`, same as `for i in $line`, you're invoking the split+glob operator (when omiting quotes around variables) which spits `$line` and expands globs (see what happens for instance if you have a `*` word in there).

Comment: @Stéphane, thanks for this clarification, I tested it and see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You will receive list of "words" which was been separated by spaces but with punctuation marks enclosed:

```
while read -a tmp_var; 
do
    for i in "${tmp_var[@]}"
    do
        var[${#var[*]}=$i
    done
done < test.txt
```

But, as usual, `test.txt` has been transformed by `tr` or `sed` or etc. in "1 word in line" list by `tr` or `sed` or etc. and `read` line by line.

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas what do you min by 'IFS' ?

Comment: @AomineDaiki `IFS=` set `Input Field Separator` as `null` to do not interfere for inner word separator if its present

Comment: in my file the only separator exist is the " " separator

Comment: i want to receive each word alone, I have a test to perform on it

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way, using whitespace as separator and all else as a word,

```
set -o noglob
words=($(cat text_file)) # use split+glob operator with glob disabled
                         # above. Splits on space tab and newline with
                         # the default value of $IFS.
```

If that words contain punctuactions and punctuations are words don't cause much trouble you could try this way.

Answer (score 1):

```
read -a WORDS -d "" < file.txt
for word in "${WORDS[@]}"
do
        echo $word
done
```

Option -a stores the words in an array.

Option -d specifies the delim string. This tells read where to stop processing the file. I've specified an empty string which causes read to continue until it gets an EOF. That is, the whole file is processed regardless of line endings.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you used `awk` in your question, here's another alternative to `tr` and `fmt`:

```
awk '{ for ( i = 1; i < NF; ++i ) print $(i); }' test.txt |
while IFS= read -r var 
do 
    echo processing: "$var" 
done
```

Note that, as with `fmt` and unlike `tr`, `awk` accepts input filenames as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following sample script which reads file `/etc/passwd` word by word.

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNT=1

FCOUNT=`cat /etc/passwd|wc -l`

while [ $COUNT -le $FCOUNT ]
do
    FTCOUNT=`awk -F ":" '{print NF,$0}' /etc/passwd|awk '{print $1}'|head -$COUNT|tail -1`
    TCOUNT=1
    while [ $TCOUNT -le $FTCOUNT ]
    do
            if [ $TCOUNT -gt $FTCOUNT ]
            then
                    FTCOUNT=""
                    break
            else
                    OUTPUT=`head -$COUNT /etc/passwd|cut -d ":" -f $TCOUNT|tail -1`
                    echo -n "${OUTPUT} "
                    sleep 2
                    TCOUNT=$(( TCOUNT + 1 ))
            fi
    done
    echo ""
    COUNT=$(( COUNT + 1 ))
done
```