# Print file Word for Word on keypress

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I want to do the following in bash: I have a textfile, and want to call a script that reads the file, waits for keystrokes from me and each time a correct button is pressed, it prints exactly one word (the next word) from the textfile.

To elaborate: Let's just say the textfile looks like the following

```
This is my
text file
```

and I am looking for keyboard buttons of the group `[[:print:]]`. So I call my script like
`./script.sh textfile`, then I press "A" and the `This`appears, then I press the Space button, still only the `This`, then I type "O" and the `is` appears, I press maybe "M" a few more times, until all of the text above is printed, and I'm done.

What I already have:

I already know how to wait for a single keypress and then do something if it works:

```
while true; do
  read -rsn1 input
    if [[ "$input" =~ "[[:print]]" ]]; then
     # do stuff on keypress
    fi
done
```

I also know how to read a file word by word: [Read File word by word](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195224/read-file-word-by-word) (I used answer of user Lambert) 
The combination of the two does not seem to work how I want it though.

If anyone has any idea on how to do this, I'd greatly appreciate it. Also, please remark if I did formulate anything unclear/wrong or if I asked in the wrong place/manner.

**Edit for clarification**
The Textfile may contain an arbitrary number of lines. Each keypress should print words *exactly* like it stands in the Textfile, i.e. it conserves spaces and newlines (think of the script I want to achieve as a delayed `cat` that prints not the whole file at once, but only Word by Word on keystroke)

Comment: Is that just one line in `textfile`, or can there be more than one?

Comment: in regards to the keys you're pressing, I see no connection between them. Can you clarify if you're expecting any alpha-numeric keystroke to print the next word?

Comment: @RudiC Yes, Textfile may contain an arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: @RobotJohnny Sorry if I did not make it clear. I am expecting any alpha-numeric keystroke, i.e. a-z A-Z 0-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not too far off for a one line file. Try arrays and get rid of your syntax errors:

```
read -a TMPARR < file
while read -n1 CH && [[ $CNT -lt ${#TMPARR[@]} ]]; do [[ "$CH" =~ [[:print:]] ]] && echo ${TMPARR[((CNT++))]}; done
```

For a multiline file, try

```
while read -a TMPARR <&3
   do   CNT=0
        [[ $CNT -lt ${#TMPARR[@]} ]] && read -sn1 CH
        while read -sn1 CH && [[ $CNT -lt ${#TMPARR[@]} ]]
          do [[ "$CH" =~ [[:print:]] ]] && echo ${TMPARR[((CNT++))]}
          done
   done  3< file
```

You have to split the input file descriptors for reading the text lines sequentially and reading from the terminal in parallel.

Comment: How could I modify this so this works for multiple lines? I added a short clarification to my question on how I want the output to look, too.

Comment: Thanks for your Input so far. This almost does the trick. It still prints every word seperate on a new line. If I use `echo -n "${TMPARR[((CNT++))]} "` I get the text separated by spaces. Still, all newlines from the original file are omitted (I am guessing because of how the Array gets created?). I want to keep the formatting exactly like in the original file though, so with all linebreaks, spaces, identations etc intact, if possible.

Comment: Would adding an `echo` between the two `done`s help?

Comment: This does the trick! Thanks and accepted.